# Using d3.geomap to display 1/0 data

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

I have CSV data where the values can be either 1, 0, or blank. I want to get this to work with **d3-geomaps**.

Here's a [Snapshot of my CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HgNM.png).

If I set it to read from column "1802", as it happens to have a mix of 1 and 0, the map works as expected. Greens = 0, Reds = 1.

However, if I read from column "1800 or 1801", as they are all 0's, all the countries are grayed out. But I want it to show greens for all the 0's.

My code:

```
var customColors = ['green','red','red'];
        var map = d3.geomap.choropleth()
            .geofile('../d3-geomap/topojson/world/countries.json')
            .colors(customColors)
            .column(y)
            .format(format)
            .legend(false)
            .unitId('Country');

       d3.csv('CSVs/data.csv', function(error, data) {  
            d3.select('.map')
                .datum(data)
                .call(map.draw, map);
```

My question is, **Is it possible to use d3.geomap to handle 1/0 data? If so, how can I make this work?**

***NOTE:***

If you're having trouble with my CSV snapshot, here's what my CSV looks like in plain text:

```
Country,1800,1801,1802
AGO,0,0,0
ARG,0,0,1
AUS,0,0,0
AUT,,0,0
```

Comment: Hi, please post text of data, not images.

Comment: @rrauenza , thanks for your reply I posted the text of data at the bottom of the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the data domain, when you create a map object as demonstrated in [this new example map](https://d3-geomap.github.io/map/choropleth/custom-domain/).

```
var map = d3.geomap.choropleth()
    .colors(['green','red'])
    .domain([0, 1])
    ....
```

<strike>Unfortunately, empty values in your CSV will then be green too, unless you convert them to `NaN` beforehand. This may well indicate a bug in d3.geomap, that I need to look into.</strike>

I fixed coloring and tooltips for empty and NaN values in release 1.0.2, which I just published.

Comment: Thank you @ramiro! I can certainly convert the blanks to "NaN". However, doing that makes the hover show NaN too. Using that same CSV example, hovering over Austria shows "1800: NaN".  Any way that can be fixed?

Comment: Ideally have it show nothing, just the country name.

Comment: The current behaviour of empty/Nan values is not ideal, I'll look into it. A somewhat ugly workaround would be to select all the `title` elements and remove those where the text contains NaN values. This would need to be done in the [postUpdate](https://d3-geomap.github.io/docs/map-properties/) function, i. e. when the map is already drawn and these elements exist.

Comment: I think I found another workaround...
var customFormat = function(d){ return (d == 'NaN') ? 'n/a' : d3.format("")(d); }

then in the code:
...
.format(customFormat)
...

Comment: Good idea to use format! Still, I hope to address making the default behaviour of the library better.

Comment: @S.C. I created a new release, where empty and NaN values are not colorized and the tooltip is just the country name.